# tcolorbox lemma numbering

Tags: tcolorbox, theorems, counters

I was wondering if there is a way to number Theorems and Lemmas the following way:

1. Theorems are numbered as [section number].[theorem number] (which I've already done), and
2. Lemmas are numbered as [section number].[theorem number].[lemma number] (which I have not done).

For example, here's what I want: the first theorem in section 4 would be Theorem 4.1. If it has two lemmas, the second one should be Lemma 4.1.2. The first lemma following Theorem 4.2 should be Lemma 4.2.1.

Below is my current code. Any help wold be greatly appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

%THEOREM
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}%
{enhanced,frame empty,interior empty,colframe=cyan!50!white, top=8mm,
    coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,colbacktitle=cyan!15!white,
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{cyan!15!white},
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{cyan!50!white,dashed},
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-4mm},
    boxed title style={sharp corners=east,boxrule=1pt},varwidth boxed title}{thm}

%LEMMA
\newtcbtheorem[]{lemma}{Lemma}%
{enhanced,frame empty,interior empty,colframe=orange!75!white, top=8mm,
    coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,colbacktitle=orange!20!white,
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{orange!20!white},
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{orange!50!white,dashed},
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-4mm},
    boxed title style={sharp corners=east,boxrule=1pt},varwidth boxed title}{thm}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{First Section}
    
        \begin{theorem}{This one should be named Theorem 1.1}{}
            theorem
        \end{theorem}

        \begin{lemma}{This one should be named Lemma 1.1.1}{}
            lemma
        \end{lemma}
    
        \begin{lemma}{This one should be named Lemma 1.1.2}{}
            lemma
        \end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by the `number within = tcb@cnt@theorem`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\makeatletter

%THEOREM
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}%
{enhanced,frame empty,interior empty,colframe=cyan!50!white, top=8mm,
    coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,colbacktitle=cyan!15!white,
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{cyan!15!white},
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{cyan!50!white,dashed},
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-4mm},
    boxed title style={sharp corners=east,boxrule=1pt},varwidth boxed title}{thm}

%LEMMA
\newtcbtheorem[number within = tcb@cnt@theorem]{lemma}{Lemma}%
{enhanced,frame empty,interior empty,colframe=orange!75!white, top=8mm,
    coltitle=black,fonttitle=\bfseries,colbacktitle=orange!20!white,
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{orange!20!white},
    borderline={0.5mm}{0mm}{orange!50!white,dashed},
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-4mm},
    boxed title style={sharp corners=east,boxrule=1pt},varwidth boxed title}{thm}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \section{First Section}
    
        \begin{theorem}{This one should be named Theorem 1.1}{}
            theorem
        \end{theorem}

        \begin{lemma}{This one should be named Lemma 1.1.1}{}
            lemma
        \end{lemma}
    
        \begin{lemma}{This one should be named Lemma 1.1.2}{}
            lemma
        \end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

The result is like this:

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you so much!! I saw this weird thing on page 111 of this manual (http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf), but instead I tried ```\thetcbcounter``` and it didn't. Almost got there but missed it :)

Comment: @Skorpion Just a bit curious, since the lemmas shall appear before the theorem, would you consider add to the counter of lemma by `1`? For example the lemma in front of Theorem 1.2 should be Lemma 1.2.1 instead of Lemma 1.1.1.

Comment: Just a side question (since StackExchange won't allow me to post another question in 40min), do you happen to know how to fix the conflict between labels of ```enumitem``` and ```tcolorbox```? With this above preamble, if you type ```\begin{enumerate}[label=arabic*)]``` in one of the theorem environments, you'd get an error, but with ```[label=arabic*)] ``` removed, it disappears.

Comment: Ahh, prior to switching to ```tcolorbox``` I've been using ```mdframed```, and I enjoyed using nested boxes. So I would first present Theorem 1.2, but then in the ```proof``` below, I would say "we need the following lemma: ```\begin{lemma}```. IMHO, it looks more aesthetically pleasing when there are nested boxes :)

Comment: @Skorpion I think this is a misspell, should be `label=\arabic*)`.

Comment: That's a misspell on my part. Even with ```label=\arabic*)``` (or ```\alph, \roman```), the same error persists: "Missing number, treated as zero." I doubt it has something to do with the ```label``` in tcolorbox, but I have no clue.

Comment: @Skorpion It works fine for me. Could you please give some sample code which produce the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116679/discussion-between-skorpion-and-jinwen).